# Java: Why is the \t escape character working inconsistently with toString()?

Tags: java, formatting, tostring

I am trying to use toString method and return a properly formatted string:

```
public String toString()
{
  return (acctNumber + "\t" + name + "\t" + fmt.format(balance));
}
```

Should format with tabs between each variable, but for the first line, the second tab doesn't seem to apply... (fake names used in the code)
This is what is printed:

```
72354   Ted Murphy$132.90
69713   Anita Gomez     $111.52
93757   Sanchit Reddy   $785.90
```

Comment: The tab is there, but `Ted Murphy` is short, so prize is closer

Answer (score 2):

It's all because the strings are of the different lengths, but tabulation idents the text to the next tab position. For such a formatting it is better to use, something like:

```
System.out.format("%32s%32s%16s", acctNumber, name, fmt.format(balance));
```

This will format your output as 32 chars for first and second variables and 16 for the third. You may vary this lengths, to make a formatting as you need. And you may need to specify data type if some of the variables are not of the String type.

You can read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)